# Most efficient method of adding 16-bit numbers, lookup table, binary addition or simple addition?

Tags: c, binary, addition, msp430

I am attempting to code the *ADD* function for an MSP-430 emulator I am attempting to build.

I was wondering if a lookup table for the addition of two 16-bit numbers would be a viable solution for efficient retrieval of my results. Alternative methods I have thought of implementing are a binary addition loop, which adds bits one by one or a simple decimal addition. I need to be able to determine the sign and the carry (if there is one).

Any specs on the micro-controller can be found [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf).

Comment: Just add them with `+`.

Comment: I agree with EugeneSh. The lookup table would have 4 billion entries. You'll need to use the arithmetic operators in C to emulate whatever the instruction does. To figure out the the flags you should do the calculations with `uint32_t` and then check the results with bitwise operators.

Comment: Even assuming that the MCU doesn't have a 16bit adder (and I believe it has), you are unlikely to outsmart the compiler optimization.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The OP is trying to write code to emulate the MSP-430.

Comment: Oh. I see. Anyway, the emulator host is some 32 or 64-bit PC, which can handle an addition with at no time.

Comment: The ADD instruction is defined on page 65, section 3.4.6.2 of the manual

Comment: Is there *any* processor or language that does not have an **add** instruction?

Comment: @WeatherVane A Turing Machine? :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. is there one?

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, there are some emulators around.. And I believe I've seen one built from LEGO.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I understand a Turing machine can move forward or backward. How can it do that without adding the required offset to the current location?

Comment: Are you considering an increment operation (+1) as an addition? If so, you are right. But having only this, the answer to this question would be different.

Comment: @EugeneSh as opposed to a Von Neumann machine, which can only multiply ;)

Comment: close++; OP should clarify what he intends to do. Unsigned addition of binary values is well defined in C and MSP430 uses the same encoding as x86, PPC, ARM, MIPS, S08, 8051, 6502, 68000, i860, etc. Unless the emulator uses gray- or other more "exotic" encodings, I do not see what he actually is asking for.

Comment: My main concerns were retrieving the carry and determining if there was an overflow to set the corresponding flags in my SRegister function.

This had to be done efficiently, least clock cycles possible and not create any segmentation faults when adding words to bytes.

I had a simple decimal addition function but it just seemed somewhat unnecessary and long. I know that many microcontrls have hardcoded results to avoid stressing the CPU so I was going to attempt a lookup table until I realized its sheer size. I am currently working on this again with a suggested answer. I'll get back to you

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple 32-bit, two's-complement arithmetic. Assuming `src` and `dst` are stored in the lower 16-bits of a `uint32_t`, the following code sequence emulates the `ADD` instruction:

```
uint32_t xor = src ^ dst;
dst += src;
flags.N = (dst >> 15) & 1;
flags.C = (dst >> 16) & 1;
flags.V = ((~xor & (src ^ dst)) >> 15) & 1;
dst &= 0xFFFF;
flags.Z = (dst == 0);
```

The result of the addition itself can be obtained by simply taking the lower 16 bits of a 32-bit addition. The N, Z, and C flags are also easy to compute. The (signed) overflow flag V is more tricky. The code basically tests whether the signs of `src` and `dst` were equal before the addition and are different afterwards.

Comment: Have you checked that carry prevents zero, as in your solution? Otherwise flags.Z = (dst & 0xFFFF) == 0;